# xcode linker error in Debug mode (duplicate symbol)

Tags: c++, xcode, boost

I ran into a problem compiling a piece of code using boost::error_info. I have a header with definitions of error codes `errors.h`

```
#ifndef ERRORS_H
#define ERRORS_H

#include <boost/exception/all.hpp>
#include <string>

enum error_num {
    ERR_IS_NOT_ZERO,
    ERR_IS_ZERO
};

typedef boost::error_info<struct tag_errno_code,error_num> errno_code;
typedef boost::error_info<struct tag_code_line,int> code_line;
typedef boost::error_info<struct tag_err_description,std::string> err_description;

struct exception_base: virtual std::exception, virtual boost::exception { };
struct integral_error: virtual exception_base { };
struct geometry_error: virtual exception_base { };

std::string error_to_str(error_num err);

#endif  /* ERRORS_H */
```

gcc doesn't give me any problems. But when I try to compile in xcode in `Debug` mode I get the following error: Apple Mach-O Linker (ld) Error

```
duplicate symbol __ZTSP13tag_code_line in:
....
duplicate symbol __ZTSP19tag_err_description in:
....
duplicate symbol __ZTSP13tag_code_line in:
....
....
ld: 6 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

And there's no problems in Release mode.

Comment: This code works fine for me for both release and debug.

Comment: @ruslo did you include the header in multiple sources? I had several source-files that were trying to use it

Comment: Yes, it works fine. Can you provide [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)?

Answer (score 2):

By trial an error I have figured out how to solve this. I needed to bring `struct tag_...` out of the `boost::error_info` template parameter:

```
struct tag_errno_code { };
struct tag_code_line { };
struct tag_err_description { };
typedef boost::error_info<tag_errno_code,error_num> errno_code;
typedef boost::error_info<tag_code_line,int> code_line;
typedef boost::error_info<tag_err_description,std::string> err_description;
```

But I don't understand why it works. Can somebody explain to me what's the difference here?

Comment: I had a nearly identical error, and I don't have a great explanation for why this solution works. I did notice that this alternate syntax is in the Boost docs:
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/exception/doc/error_info.html

I discussed with a colleague, and our best guess is that the compiler isn't able to handle the struct correctly when it is defined only within the typedef line, resulting in multiple definitions of the struct. 

Thanks for posting your solution!